# Calculate $\int _0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 (\pi \omega)}{(\omega ^2 -1)^2}d \omega$

Tags: calculus, fourier-series

We define $f: \mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R} $ by:
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{matrix}
\sin x, & |x|\leq \pi\\ 
0, & |x|>\pi
\end{matrix}\right.$$
A. Find the Fourier transform of $f$. Answer: $$F(\omega)=\frac{2 i \sin(\omega \pi)}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\omega^2-1)}$$
B. Calculate the integral $$\int _0^\infty \frac{\sin^2 (\pi \omega)}{(\omega ^2 -1)^2}d \omega$$
Any help? I am referred this "identity" but I don't know what it means and how to use it.
$$||f||_2=||F(\omega)||_2$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**A.**
$$\widehat{f}(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}e^{-i\omega x}\sin x\,dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Im\left(\int_{-\pi}^{+\pi}e^{(1-i\omega)x}\,dx\right)=\frac{2i\sin(\pi\omega)}{\sqrt{2\pi}(\omega^2-1)}.$$
**B.**
Since Parseval's theorem gives:
$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|\widehat{f}(\xi)|^2\,d\xi = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|f(x)|^2\,dx = \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^2 x\,dx = \pi,$$
but the LHS of the last identity is:
$$\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(\pi\omega)}{(\omega^2-1)^2}\,d\omega = \frac{4}{\pi}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(\pi\omega)}{(\omega^2-1)^2}\,d\omega,$$
it follows that:

> $$\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\sin^2(\pi\omega)}{(\omega^2-1)^2}\,d\omega=\frac{\pi^2}{4}.$$

Comment: That's great. Thank you very much.

Comment: @UdiBehar: you're welcome.

Comment: @ Jack D'Aurizio: Could you give me a hint with this one: I need to find the 2 following int's:$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi \omega )\sin(\frac{1}{2}\pi \omega )}{1-\omega ^2}$$
and
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{\sin(\pi \omega )\sin(2\pi \omega )}{1-\omega ^2}$$

Comment: Hint: you already know the Fourier (inverse) transform of $\frac{\pi\omega}{1-\omega^2}$. Exploit the fact that the integral of $f\cdot g$ is the convolution between the Fourier transforms of $f$ and $g$.

Comment: Alternative hint: the two integrals can be computed also through standard complex analytic techniques. The first integral is $\frac{\pi}{2}$ and the second one is zero.